# Web/browser-oriented open source machine learning projects?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, classification, weka, nltk

Applying machine learning techniques, more specifically text mining techniques, in browser environment (mainly Javascript) or as a web application is not a very widely discussed topic.

I want to build my own web application / browser extension that can accomplish certain level of text classification / visualization techniques. I would like to know, if there is any open source projects that apply text mining techniques in web application or even better as browser extensions?

So far, these are the projects/discussions I gathered with days of random searching:

**For text mining in web application:**

- http://text-processing.com/ with [demo](http://text-processing.com/demo/) (Close source, with limited api)
- [uClassify](http://www.uclassify.com/Default.aspx) (close source, no info about library base)

**For machine learning in Javascript:**

- [Discussion](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1704648) on the possibility about Machine learning in
  JavaScript. (mainly about saying Node.js is going to change the landscape)
- [brain - javascript supervised machine learning](http://harthur.github.com/brain/)
- A [demo project](http://www.dusbabek.org/~garyd/bayes/) with Naive Bayes implemented in Javascript

For web application text mining, the architect that I can think of:

- Python libraries (e.g. NLTK or scikit-learn) + Django
- Java libraries (a lot) + Play! framework
- Even R based + [rApache](http://rapache.net/)

Comment: Who gives me a vote down? Could you explain why? I don't think my question meets any one of "does not show any research effort; it is unclearn or not useful".....

Comment: The evil is among us. Why the @Bahaus's answer is -1?

Comment: @Mustafa Not sure, could be the same person....

Comment: how about visualization techniques! which technique that you have found more suitable for JS, Are you using MongoDB to retrieve the data from it!

Comment: Maybe it was voted -1 because it's off-topic according to [What topics can I ask about here?][http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic]. Specifically point 4  says that  "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow... " are off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

Some popular machine learning libraries:

Python - [PyBrain](http://pybrain.org/)

Apache - [Mahout](http://mahout.apache.org/)

Answer (score -1):

I'll give you my favourities:

- Brain.js
- ConvNetJS

It has been 7 years since this question was asked, but there is a chance that machine learning will get native browsers support: https://webmachinelearning.github.io/

(just make sure you like posts in github issues about adding training capabilities, otherwise you might end up only with some 3rd party models support :-) )